# Convert this JavaScript to PowerShell 2

Tags: javascript, powershell, powershell-2.0

It throws errors in PowerShell 2, can someone help me convert to PS2 please?

```
var args = WScript.Arguments
var FSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var src = FSO.OpenTextFile(args(0));
var dst = FSO.CreateTextFile(args(0) + ".tmp");
var tmpline;
var re = new RegExp("%" + args(1) + "%","ig");

while(!src.AtEndOfStream)
{
    tmpline = src.ReadLine();
    tmpline = tmpline.replace(re, args(2));
    dst.WriteLine(tmpline);
}

src.Close();
dst.Close();
FSO.DeleteFile(args(0));
FSO.MoveFile(args(0) + ".tmp", args(0));
```

Comment: What is your PowerShell code so far?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Get-Content $args[0] `
  | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "%$($args[1])%", $args[2] } `
  | Out-File ($args[0] + '.tmp')
Move-Item ($args[0] + '.tmp') $args[0] -Force
```

provided I understood your code correctly. You may need to add the `-Encoding` parameter with a suitable argument to `Out-File`, though.

Comment: how is that ? I am very new to this.

Comment: I need to run Install-ClamAgent.ps1 , in the same directory is that JavaScript.js file but when run in PW V2.0 it throws a bunch of errors.

Comment: PowerShell tells you where to look it up, if you try executing a script. In any case: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` would be a start.